# Data too long at row 1

Tags: c#, mysql

im trying to update a row in my database called gestion_concour using c#

```
private void Modifier_Concour_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string input_Code = Code.Text;
    string input_Des = Des.Text;
    string input_Spe = Spe.Text;
    string selected = ConcourList.Text;
    MySqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    builder.Server = "127.0.0.1";
    builder.UserID = "root";
    builder.Password = "root";
    builder.Database = "gestion_concour";
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(builder.ToString());
    connection.Open();
    string query = "update gestion_concour.concour set Code = @N_Code, Designation = @N_Des, Specialite = @N_Spe where Code = @A_Code";
    MySqlCommand mcmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
    mcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@A_Code", selected);
    mcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@N_Code", input_Code);
    mcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@N_Des", input_Des);
    mcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@N_Spe", input_Spe);
    MySqlDataReader myReader;
    try
    {
        myReader = mcmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
        }
        Code.Clear();
        Des.Clear();
        Spe.Clear();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    connection.Close();
    Fill_Combo();
    fill_grid();
}
```

i fill the textbox so the query goes like

```
update gestion_concour.concour set Code = 'CAEPST', Designation = 'Concours Accées a EPST', Specialite = 'EPST' where Code = '3';
```

and i got this 
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mf7RC.png)
i tried to pass the query in woekbench and it work just fine.
so what is the prob 
(Code is VARCHAR(10))

Comment: `mcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@N_Code", input_Des);` looks wrong

Comment: I suppose that your problem could be fixed simply adding a Trim after the ConcourList.Text

Comment: @Wimmel sorry just frapp error

Comment: @IlyesGHOMRANI what is the value of `input_Code`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably do these things to figure out what went wrong -

1. Check the database if `Code` column is really varchar(10).
2. If it is, then try checking the value of the string `input_Code` if its really "CAEPST".
3. If it checks, then make sure to trim the textbox before inserting it.
4. You can also test to update just the column.
5. Another option is, we can use the actual textbox as your value. Like this - 
   `mcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@N_Code", Code.Text.ToString());`
6. Or we can also do it like this, just to see if it really goes thru - 
   `mcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@N_Code", "CAEPST");`

Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are using `ExecuteReader`. If you want to exec a Update command, you should use `ExecuteNonQuery`.So it would be:

```
try
{
    int i = mcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Also this lines seems wrong:

```
mcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@N_Code", input_Des);
mcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@N_Des", input_Des);
```

It seems you are adding the designation instead of the code. Probably it should be:

```
mcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@N_Code", input_Code );
```

Changing this won't hurt also, just to make sure there are no spaces behind causing the problem:

```
string input_Code = Code.Text.Trim();
string input_Des = Des.Text.Trim();
string input_Spe = Spe.Text.Trim();
string selected = ConcourList.Text.Trim();
```

Comment: Correct but this hardly fixes the problem

Comment: how to change it ?? sorry i'm new

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the wrong variable for you parameter. Try

```
mcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@N_Code", input_Code );
```

instead of

```
mcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@N_Code", input_Des);
```

Comment: still the same probleme

Comment: @IlyesGHOMRANI what is the value of `input_Code`?

Comment: @IlyesGHOMRANI are you absolutely certain that `Code` is varchar(10)? When you look in the debugger, is the value of `input_Code` "CAEPST"?